# WCF SOAP Web Service Handling Bad Enums - C# .Net

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, enums

I have a WCF SOAP Web Service built using svcutil to generate the contract classes. The WSDL has enums and thus the default is to deserialize the XML to an enum class. This works great when the user sends in the correct enum.

`<priceType>List</priceType>`

`<priceType>Net</priceType>`

However, if the user enters a bogus value:

`<priceType>I love dogs</priceType>`

The deserializer throws and exception and they get a SOAP Fault that there was a server error. How could I respond with a better error message that their enum value is invalid?

Comment: It is not the task of WCF (Communication layer) to validate user input. This should never occur.

Comment: One approach would be to replace enum (which is not always safe to use in cross-service scenarios just like in your case) with a class providing similar functionality. For example, as described [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/). This should make unexpected values deserializable and you should be able to check for valid values in your own code and then provide a response in a convenient way.